# getting git log output in prettyformat

Tags: json, git, graph, git-bash, git-log

I have this command:`git log --all --pretty=format:'%n{%n  "CommitHash": "%H",%n  "Author": "%an",%n  "AuthorEmail": "%ae",%n  "Date": "%ad",%n  "Message": "%f",%n},'`

Ho can I modify it to get this: `"Merge":"....."` and this:  `Merge branch 'master' of ..........`

Those 2 things appear when you use the `git log --all --graph` command,  but I trying to put the info that I would get with that command in the pretty format that I put above,  and until now I could get everything except those 2 things.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the `"Merge":"....."` with a format: it's simply not available that way.

You *can* get all the parent hash IDs using `%p` (abbreviated parent hash IDs) or `%P` (full parent hash IDs).  Note, however, that you will get parent hash IDs of non-merge commits as well.  The difference is, of course, that if there are two or more parent hash IDs—these will be separated by spaces—the commit in question is a merge commit.

The `Merge branch 'master' of <url>` text is simply the body of the commit message, in a merge commit in which whoever made the merge let `git pull` dictate the body contents.  This is available via `%b` (body only) or `%B` (subject plus body).  Once again, you will get this for *all* commits, not just merge commits.

If you are attempting to produce valid JSON from arbitrary commits (including message bodies), you should not attempt this solely with `--pretty=format:...` directives, but rather with an external program that can make any necessary changes to the message-body text so that it does not disrupt the JSON stream.  For instance, a commit message body that contains a double quote or a newline will be a problem.